# Cannot set dimAmount for BottomSheetDialogFragment in Android 13+

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat, android-bottomsheetdialog, android-api-33

BottomSheetDialogFragment accepts only dipAmount of 1.0f (non-transparent black background), 0.99f and less are fully transparent background, this seems to be affecting only API 33+. Styles.xml attributes not working too. What should i do to set background dim to standart 0.32f?

I've tried setting attributes

```
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.3</item>
```

Not worked. Then in code

```
requireDialog().window?.apply {
    addFlags(FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)

    val lp = attributes
    lp?.dimAmount = 0.32f
    attributes = lp

    setDimAmount(0.99f)
}
```

It's still absolutely transparent. But if i'll change to

```
setDimAmount(1.0f)
```

then BottomSheetDialogFragment's background will be absolutely black.

Comment: After updating Android Studio to Hedgehog, dim does not work on API level 29+ (Android 10+)

Comment: @DraganStojanov I am having the exact same problem. Has anyone opened a bug report with them already?

Comment: Issue has already been opened about this, still not fixed as far as I can tell: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/289117017

Answer (score 1):

Possible, temporary solution:

```
    val dimmedBackgroundColor = Color.argb(82,0,0,0)//alpha = .32F 

    requireDialog().window?.apply {
        setDimAmount(0f)// remove dimmed back on older devices
        decorView.setBackgroundColor(dimmedBackgroundColor)
    }
```